# How to update React site in GoDaddy through CPanel?

Tags: reactjs, build, updates, web-hosting, host

I hosted my react js website on godaddy. I did this by uploading all the build folder files to public_html in the C panel file manager. Now I have updated the local website and I have created it again, so I want to update it in godaddy. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel does not have a feature to update **only** files that have changed, but you can achieve your goal of uploading the latest version of your site by erasing the files you originally uploaded, then uploading the new ones. This makes sure to also erase any files you might not be using anymore.

If this answer still does not satisfy your need to keep the site updated with the latest build, you can look into two alternatives:

1. Upload your files using an FTP client, this way you can have control to only update files that have changed
2. Use the CLI program `rsync` to synchronize your local build directory with the directory in your GoDaddy server, this also allows you to only update files that have changes and it also has an option to delete files in the server that have been deleted locally.